# How to mock Vaadin components with Jest/Vitest in a Vue project

Tags: vue.js, testing, mocking, vaadin, vue-testing-library

I'm currently working in a Vue+javascript project that uses Vaadin components.
I'm trying to test our code using vitest + vue testing library, but I'm having problems mocking the third party components.

I found a way using stubs https://test-utils.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/stubs-shallow-mount.html, but the solution does not fit properly, because to use them I need the components to be Vue and they are not. So I have to wrap all vaadin components individually in a `<template>` and then mock them with the stub. Too much work for a huge project.

I'd rather find a way mocking them using `__mocks__` file, but that does not work. Well, what happens is that I'm not able to connect the tests with the mocks file, they just don't see eachother.
This is how I set it up (but I've tried many names):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYTUy.png)

This is the location of the combobox inside node-modules:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMuTM.png)

Any ideas of how can I do it?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking
a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).